# AngularJS - Load more data from remote server at bottom of page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to AngularJS and I am trying to develop a simple App with Angular and IonicFramework.
I load some data from a remote server with $http.get() and this works well, but I want to optimize that, so I don't want to load all entries at start.
I want to load more results from server, if the user is at the end of the page.

E.g. I load 10 entries, if the user scrolls down after the last entry it should refresh automaticly and load more entries.
I hope someone can help me to do something like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **ngInfiniteScroll** module for that http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/